# Wordpress theme Shop Isle video

Tags: html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm building a Wordpress page using shop isle theme.

The theme features a front page video which I am trying to make link out to another page.

The section is contained in a div and also has a div YTPoverlay

This is what I have tried:

```
<!-- Youtube player start-->
<div class="YTPOverlay">
<a href="http://www.google.com"></a>
</div>

   <div class="video-player" data-property="{videoURL:'<?php echo 
$shop_isle_yt_link; ?>', containment:'.module-video', startAt:0, 
mute:true, autoPlay:true, loop:true, opacity:1, showControls:false, 
showYTLogo:false, vol:25}"></div>

   <!-- Youtube player end -->

   <?php
echo '</div>';
endif;
echo '</section>';
```

And I have added this to the CSS:

```
.YTPOverlay a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Which hasn't worked.

Any Ideas?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change from:

containment:'.module-video'

to:

containment:'.YTPOverlay'